# Twig Object Attributes of ParseObject

Tags: parse-platform, twig

I'm using Slim + Twig + ParseSDK, I can retrieve the objects from the Parse Database but when I want to access them through Twig it doesn't print anything. I have used `{{ dump() }}` and it shows the values stored on the object.

How can I access the values on the ParseObject?

The `{{ dump(object) }}` prints the following:

```
object(Parse\ParseObject)[38]
  protected 'serverData' => 
    array (size=14)
      'alias' => string 'testt' (length=5)
      'city' => string '---' (length=3)
      'country' => string 'México' (length=7)
      'exterior' => string '411' (length=3)
      'interior' => string '---' (length=3)
      'municipality' => string '---' (length=3)
      'neighborhood' => string 'xxxxx' (length=11)
      'notification' => boolean true
      'position' => 
        object(Parse\ParseGeoPoint)[41]
          private 'latitude' => float 9.5
          private 'longitude' => float 9.5
      'state' => string 'Colima' (length=7)
      'street' => string 'Madre mía' (length=21)
      // Not complete...
```

How could I print the neighborhood, I have tried `{{ address.neighborhood }}` but it doesn't shows anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: {{ object.serverData.neighborhood }}

Comment: this {{ object.serverData.neighborhood }} returns null :( or {{ object.serverData }}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I inspected the ParseObject class and could not find anything else that could be of use than the getters. I'm not sure if it's the perfect solution, but it does work using the getters.

So in your case this should be working: `{{ address.get('neighborhood') }}`.

Let me know if it helped!
Cheers

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, at the end I had to create a new object on the server side (php).

Comment: That's weird, looping through objects and creating a new one in the controller is definitely not the way to go. The above code snippet should be working with Parse 1.0.4/Twig 1.16.3/PHP 5.6.